# Why define lightningMessageFields in Lightning Message Service?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service

I am wondering something.
In the XML file of a lightning message channel I can specify lightningMessageFields or I can omit this. Either way messages on the channel function correctly whatever you put into them.
Example one with no fields:

```
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <masterLabel>TestChannel</masterLabel>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <description></description>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

If i create a payload like this, it works:

```
let message = {request: true};
publish(this.context, TESTCHANNEL, message);
```

Example two with a field called 'success':

```
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <masterLabel>TestChannel</masterLabel>
        <isExposed>true</isExposed>
        <description></description>
        <lightningMessageFields>
               <fieldName>success</fieldName>
        <description></description>
    </lightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

The same payload still works:

```
let message = {request: true};
publish(this.context, TESTCHANNEL, message);
```

So why bother with fields?
If any one has any insight into this, Id be very interested.
Thanks.
Dane

Comment: Already answered here : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/327767/45062

Comment: Thank you. I had looked around quite a bit before i wrote my question.